# Am I understanding this probability problem correctly?

Tags: probability

Find $P(2 < X < 6) \mid A, B)$, where $A = \{2 < X < 7\}$ and $B = 
\{1 < X < 5\}$.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Step 1: $$P(A,B) = A \cap B = \{2 < X < 5\}$$
Step 2: $$P(2<X<6\mid A,B) = \frac{(2<X<6)\cap(A\cap B)}{A\cap B}$$
Step 3: $$=\frac{P(3,4)}{P(3,4)}$$
Step 3: $$=1$$

Comment: Note that $P(2 < X < 6 \mid A, B)$ means $P(2 < X < 6 \mid A \cap B)$, and that $A \cap B = \{2 < X < 5\}$.

Comment: I've updated the OP. Does that look correct?

Comment: Not sure how you got step 3. Think about this intuitively for a moment. If you know that $2 < X < 5$, what's the probability that $2 < X < 6$? You can answer this without knowing anything about how $X$ is distributed (as long as $P(2 < X < 5) > 0$).

Comment: There is something strange in step $2$: we have $P(2<X<5)\leqslant P(2<X<6)$, so the RHS is $\geqslant 1$.

Comment: @Bungo {2 < X < 6} = {3,4,5} and {2 < X < 5} = {3,4}. I assumed {3,4,5} and {3,4} cancel out to {5} on top.

Comment: @Taladris Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Jon: your formula for conditional probabilities is wrong: you have to use $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. As some deleted comment said, the final answer should be $1$.

Comment: @Taladris I've updated the OP, could you double check? Is the final answer "1" as in 100% or P(1)?

Comment: That's better but you have to use $P$ for probabilities. As it stands $(3,4)$ is an interval and you cannot divide an interval by an interval.

Comment: But $$\frac{P(3,4)}{P(3,4)}$$ is 1 right?

Comment: Is $X$ constrained to be an integer? That isn’t stated anywhere in the OP.

Comment: @Bungo X is a poisson random variable